# Delphi menu choice

Tags: delphi, menu, listener

My question is how to catch which menu item was pressed in some form? For an example :

I have a form with a button. When I pressed the button the menu of the application will be on focus and the child form wait to choose a menu item. After I choose one the child form show a message with the name of the menu item which I pressed.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: After reading the comments it seems that your three little words "In some form" have a whole depth of unexpressed question in them.  Please ask questions in detail, and spell it out for everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 1/ By default you set all the TMenuItem OnClick event handler to Nil.
- 2/ When you click the form button you assign an event to each TMenuItem, this event will be only called once, and will record the 'trigger'.
- 3/ When the event is called you reset all the TMenuitem.OnClick to Nil
- 4/ To make this easyer, you store all your MenuItems in a TList.

example:

global variables (private declaration in TMyForm):

```
MyTriggerItem: TMenuItem; // used as pointer
MyMenuItemList: TList; // used to store all TMenuItem which are 'listened to'
```

your TButton handler:

```
Procedure TMyForm.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
Var
  i: Integer;
Begin
  For i:= 0 To Pred(MyMenuItemList.Count) Do TMenuItem(MyMenuItemList[i]).OnCLick := CommonMenuItemClick;    
End;
```

your TMenuItem event handler:

```
Procedure TMyForm.CommonMenuItemClick(Sender: TObject);
Var
  i: Integer;
Begin
  MyTriggerItem := TMenuItem(Sender);
  For i:= 0 To Pred(MyMenuItemList.Count) Do TMenuItem(MyMenuItemList[i]).OnCLick := Nil;
End;
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this is a direct answer to your question:

```
procedure TMyForm.MenuItemClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage((Sender as TMenuItem).Caption);
end;
```

This event handler should be connected to each menu item that you wish to behave this way.

---

It seems that you want some centralised logging or monitoring of the execution of menu items. If you use actions and associate these with your menu items then you can get an application wide notification that an action has been executed. Drop a `TApplicationEvents` object onto your main form and handle its `OnActionExecute` event. Like this:

```
procedure TMyForm.ApplicationEvents1ActionExecute(Action: TBasicAction; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  ShowMessage((Action as TAction).Caption);
end;
```

This will fire whenever any event in your app is executed.

Comment: This is the easy way. My problem is how to catch the event of the menu item and get it name.

Comment: @Jordan Clearly I don't understand something. Can you explain what this answer lacks and expand on exactly what you want.

Comment: OK. When you press one of the menu item in a menu bar in Delphi application there is an event which execute something,some action. I want to catch this event and to display on a message dialog, for an example, the name of the menu item.

Comment: Nope, I still don't understand.

Comment: In this web site : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_(computing) is explain everything about the events. I just want to catch this events in a different form and show which menu item if it is a menu item instance was clicked!

Comment: I already know what an event is. The problem is that I can't work out what you mean. You want to detect an event from a different form? That's not how events in Delphi work. Events work by running an event handler.

Comment: @Jordan: that is a completly different beast that what your main question ask, I suggest that you edit it to make it clearer. David: he wants to detect form1.event in form2 without sending a message from 1 to 2. I guess that would mean spying on 1's message loop.

Comment: @Lepidosteus I think I'm getting there. FWIW, there is only one message loop in a thread (excluding those associated with modal windows). I think I have a solution now.